# Remove Select2 required field dynamical

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have set value for select2 like this on a change event

```
 $("#myselectBox").select2().val(data.id).trigger('change.select2');
```

So value get changed/selected but while I am submitting the form it still says field is required.

So how can I make select2 required false at this moment?

```
   $('#myselectBox').attr('required', false);
```

OR

```
  $("#myselectBox").select2().trigger('change');
```

Comment: so you need to remove required from select on submit ?

Comment: yes you are correct..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to the library validating whether the select list has a value or not. Using the browser's default validation works (tested in Firefox).

```js
$("#myselectBox").select2();

function autoSelect() {

  $("#myselectBox").val(1);
  $("#myselectBox").change();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="GET">
  <select id="myselectBox" name="select" required=true>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">An option 1</option>
    <option value="2">An option 2</option>
    <option value="3">An option 3</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="autoSelect()">Select with JS</button>
```

Source: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Comment: You means $("#myselectBox").change(); ?

Comment: I tried here various possible way but strange no one is working

Comment: @SunilRawat Please add JS or jQuery library used to validate whether a field is required or not.